# set separate url and description for URL-field via javascript

Tags: splistitem, url

I've got a list item with a field of type URL. 
As you know, an URL-field consists of two parts: a description and a URL.

Using javascript to update a field that consists of one part is easy, you just do something like

```
 myItem.set_item('MyTextField', 'MyValue');
myItem.update();
```

But how do I update a URL-field that way? I've tried the following

```
var URLObj = { URL: 'http://myurl', Description:'this is a description' }; 
myItem.set_item('MyURLField', URLObj);
```

but it fails during set_item,

Also tried this:

```
    var URLField = myItem.get_item('MyURLField');
URLField.set_url('http://myurl');
URLField.set_description('this is a description');
```

But get_item only returns null.

The URL-field I'm trying to set is initially empty, so that's probobly causing some problems, seems like getting empty fields don't return anything ,just null.

So any ideas on what I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee549053.aspx) says that when assign a value to a list item field you must provide a string, but its not true for complicated fields such url or others. You must use this approach:

```
var fvalue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
fvalue.set_url("http://google.com");
fvalue.set_description("my description");
newListItem.set_item("linkfield", fvalue);
```

Useful resource about CSOM javascript classes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557057.aspx)